# Array of values. Set minimum value to 0%, maximum value to 100% and find coefficient for all items

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to find a solution with my task for several hours straight without real improvements, so I will try to seek help from you.

Let's say, we have an array with values.

```
let values = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
let maxValue = Math.max(...values);
let minValue = Math.min(...values);
values.map((item) => ((item) / maxValue));
```

As you can see, we are receiving 
[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1], but what I want is to receive array like 
[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1] out of it.

My logic is kinda shocked with this challenge, so I hope you could help me.
I tried to set first value to 0 and last value to 1, but still nothing.
Tried, to play with (item-minValue) / maxValue also, we are receiving first value as a 0, but it doesn't help.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, I don't need to sort it, I need to find out coefficient, read question, please.

Comment: let values = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
let maxValue = Math.max(...values);
let minValue = Math.min(...values);
const percentVal = values.map((item) => ((item-minValue) / maxValue));
const coefficient = (1 - percentVal[percentVal.length-1]) / (percentVal.length - 1)
percentVal.map((item, index) => item + index * coefficient);

Comment: please take a look at the code in previous comment.

Comment: Exactly, thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for `(item-minValue) / (maxValue-minValue)`?

Comment: Lol, I am feeling soo dumb right now, after spending several hours, without doubt, I could tell, I was just overthinking, thank you guys!

Comment: @MihhailS added the comment as answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at following code which focusses on finding a value that can be added to output array [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8] to make it [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1].
Also it will always work on sorted arrays.

```
let values = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
let maxValue = Math.max(...values);
let minValue = Math.min(...values);
const fractionsArr = values.map((item) => ((item-minValue) / maxValue));
const coefficient = (1 -fractionsArr[fractionsArr.length-1]) / (fractionsArr.length - 1)
return fractionsArr.map((item, index) => item + index * coefficient);
```

OR

```
let values = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
let maxValue = Math.max(...values);
let minValue = Math.min(...values);
return values.map((item) => ((item-minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)));
```

Comment: `percentVal` is a confusing name, as nothing in there is a percentage

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the `minValue` from both `item` and `maxValue` when mapping the values:

```js
let values = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
let maxValue = Math.max(...values);
let minValue = Math.min(...values);
values.map((item) => ((item - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)));
```